# issue with QTtestrunner in cppunit

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, cppunit

I have a project use cppunit for unit test, I used QTtestrunner to show the result here is the code

```
CPPUNIT_NS::QtUi::TestRunner testrunner;  
testrunner.addTest (CPPUNIT_NS::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry().makeTest());
testrunner.run (true);
```

but I have this message in compiling:

```
src/main.cpp:78: undefined reference to 'CppUnit::QtTestRunner::QtTestRunner()'
src/main.cpp:79: undefined reference to CppUnit::QtTestRunner::addTest(CppUnit::Test*)'                 
src/main.cpp:80: undefined reference to CppUnit::QtTestRunner::run(bool)'
src/main.cpp:91: undefined reference to 'CppUnit::QtTestRunner::~QtTestRunner()'
```

I know there is a problem of linking but I include all what I need libcppunit.a and libcppunit.so

Comment: Can you please add your command line parameters that use for linking?

Comment: For compiling I use bjam and here is my code  `use-Library =  <library-path>UT_Cpp_Test/main/libs/
               <library-file>UT_Cpp_Test/main/libs/libcppunit.a;` this is for the static lib .                                                                                            `exe UT_Cpp_Test_$(GL_OS_TAG)
    :      [  glob   src/*.cpp  ]
    :       $(usage-requirements)
     $(use-Library)
     <library-path>UT_Cpp_Test/libs
        <find-shared-library>cppunit`  and this for execution.

Comment: In fact I figure out that I didn't compile the qttesrunnerlib so I'am trying to compile it after installing qt and I need to link against the created lib, thank you any way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt version difference is the problem. You can download this [patch](http://sourceforge.net/p/cppunit/patches/46/)
It converts to Qt3, then you can convert it to Qt4 using "qt3to4".

Also you need to add qt3 support into your pro file when you are using qttestrunner.a library.

```
QT += qt3support
```